# How to make the keywords in \cref compatible in the enumerate environment

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

My problem is as follows,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\Crefdefpart}[2]{
  \nameCref{#1}~\hyperref[#2]{\labelcref*{#1}\ref*{#2}}
  }
\crefname{enumi}{part}{parts}

\begin{document}
Stated in terms of choice functions, Zermelo's first formulation of AC reads:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{enum:AC1} Any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function. 
    
    \cref{enum:AC1} can be reformulated in terms of \textit{indexed} or
    
    \item[AC2]\label{enum:AC2} Any indexed collection of sets has a choice function.
    
    \cref{enum:AC2}: Informally speaking, \textbf{AC2} amounts to the assertion that a variable set with an element at each stage has a variable element.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The result is in the following

[image]

**Questions:**

1. If I want to let \cref recognize the keyword in the square bracket
   of \item, e.g., AC2, what shall I do?
2. Why do both /cref's refer to the same thing? Any clue about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ask, "why do both `\cref` [calls] refer to the same thing? That would be because `\item[AC2]` -- by design -- does *not* increment the counter `enumi`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your quick response, I just posted the whole code for your convenience